# DSP library for making an android application..?

Tags: android, android-ndk, signal-processing

I am familiar with basic android application development and now assigned with the task of
 making an android application which needs to perform DSP functions for audio signal   processing. I would like to have basic knowledge about the C/C++ libraries which i can use   along with android ndk and embed it into my android application.
  I have already checked and went through many solutions available here but none satisfied my requirement, please share the links from where i can get such libraries which i can use.
  Sorry if my question is not clear to answer as i am new to asking questions here.

Thank you for your response...!!!

Comment: while searching for some libraries in this case i have some libraries like aquila and also something as pure data....but i am not so sure thats the thing i need..?

Comment: This type of "recommend a library" question is generally off topic, and even more so when you've failed to give any information about what your requirements actually are.

Comment: i need to built an android application which records the sound of an musical instrument and have to perform dsp functions on that recorded sound may be like FFT. So i needed to use a DSP library(open source) which will provide me this functions. I think this will make clear my requirements.